# How can I make sense of binary stl files so that I can parse them using Python?

Tags: hex, binaryfiles

I am trying to write a python program that takes a binary STL file and parses out all the vertices, but I can't figure out the binary files with a hex editor. I have read a few tutorial on hex and I understand that each 2 hex digits represents a byte and you add these together in even numbers to represent numbers or characters, but when I look at what they make it still never makes sense. I have found the format of a binary stl file here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)). But the hex editor just spits out random characters like @, a whole lot of . (what do these do?), @, ", *, ect. How can I find which hex characters represent which vertices, which are the spacing characters, which are the normal characters, ect.

Answer (score 0):

search out the documentation about the `struct` package in python 
This is how you want to read binary data